# cx_Freeze: Python error in main script (function not found)

Tags: python-3.x, windows-xp, cx-freeze

I am trying to create an exe from python script using cx_freeze
I have been able to create the build and test it successfully on win7 but whenever I try to run the exe on win xp I get the following error.
Have tried uninstalling and reinstalling cx_freeze but it wont help.
I am using python 3.4

```
AttributeError: function 'SetProcessDPIAware' not found
```

[Complete error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jypqf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.
Build the application on win xp pc.

Add the following lines to your setup file-

`os.environ["TCL_LIBRARY"]=r"C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6"
os.environ["TCLLIBPATH"]=r"C:\Python34\tcl\tcl8.6"
os.environ["TK_LIBRARY"]=r"C:\Python34\tcl\tk8.6"`

All must point to the correct tcl paths within the python setup.
In my case it was looking for tcl in some other location due to some environment variable confusion.
And build your script using cx_freeze again.
Will work like a charm.